# ExpressJS showing different view partials to logged in vs non logged in users

Tags: express

How can I show different things to users depending on whether they are logged in. A very simple use case:

- Show login button for non logged in users
- Show welcome {username} | logout otherwise

I believe I should be checking the session but how can I do so without passing the session (or just username/id) into the view everytime

Comment: why are you against passing the session to the view? isn't that what the session is for?

Comment: I was thinking the view should only recieve what it needs, for read only purposes. Anyways, how can I pass the session to the view without having to do so in all routes? `res.render("something", { session: req.session })`

Comment: read only purposes for whom? look at `res.locals` for express 3.0 (forgot what it was for 2.x)

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a dynamic helper "user", e.g.:

```
app.dynamicHelpers({
  user: function(req, res){
    var roles, name;

    if (req.session && req.session.auth == true) {
      roles = ['member'];
      name = (req.session.user) ? req.session.user.name : 'Registered member';
      id = (req.session.user) ? req.session.user.id : null;
    }
    else {
      roles = ['guest'];
      name = 'Guest';
      id = null;
    }

    return {
      name: name, 
      id: id,
      roles: roles,
      isGuest: roles.indexOf('guest') !== -1,
      isMember: roles.indexOf('member') !== -1,
      isAdmin: roles.indexOf('admin') !== -1
    }
  }
});
```

2) In the view (if you use Jade) use following conditional notation:

```
if user.isGuest
  h2 Please register!
if user.isMember
  h2 Hello, member!
```